# Devise nested attributes form field not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am having trouble viewing the nested attributes field in my form. I am in the `jobs/new` view and I want have a User form that creates a job as well as a user.

I have everything in this answer [Rails 4.0 with Devise. Nested attributes Unpermited parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767449/rails-4-0-with-devise-nested-attributes-unpermited-parameters)

I have also checked out this [Nested attributes not showing up in simple form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528582/nested-attributes-not-showing-up-in-simple-form)

But the latter answer already applies to my code and it is not showing up. My Code:

**Job Model**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**User Model**

```
has_many :jobs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
```

**Jobs/new view**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>


  <%= f.fields_for :jobs do |builder| %>
    <%= render "job_detail_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Enter email", class: "full-width form-field" %>

<% end %>
```

**_job_details_fields**

```
<%= f.text_area :job_description, placeholder: "Job description..." %>
```

The `:job_description` text_area is not showing. If I change the nested attributes form to something like `f.fields_for :job`, it will then show but on submission of the form I get **unpermitted paramater job** as an error. I am pretty sure `jobs` is correct but I don't know why it is not showing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh going over the Rails Cast it looks like I need to `build` the :job_description.

This fixed it `1.times { @resource.jobs.build }` in my Jobs controller.

**Jobs Controller**

```
def new
    @resource ||= User.new
    1.times { @resource.jobs.build }
end
```

Comment: you don't need the `1.times` just `@resource.jobs.build`